# Reading loginame after http authentification

Tags: php, cakephp, http-authentication

I seem not to be able to wrap my head around this.. How can I read out the loginname that was used for http authentification using PHP, more specifically, cakePHP? I am using the Security Component of cakePHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally:

`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];`

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

In Cake try this in the controller maybe:

`$this->data['User']['username']`

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1261/login

Comment: Thank you, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] gives me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $this->Auth->user()?
Just write debug($this->Auth->user()); somewhere in your Action to see what's actually in there.

Comment: But I am not using the Auth component.